# How do I read this CSV in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, csv

I have to work on this Student Performance data set from here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00320/ ,

I managed to import the student-mat.csv in notebook but I checked the excel and saw everything about each student is written only into the very first box of each row, and is 'separated' by quotation marks so I cant make the computer read each column distinctively?

[image: you can see here]

How do I make this readable and into an actual table in notebook?

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Why are you posting about excel? But your tagging this with Python?

Answer (score 0):

They are delimited by ";", so you will have to use the delimiter parameter of `read_csv`.

```
student_mat=pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", delimiter=";")
student_pos=pd.read_csv("student-por.csv", delimiter=";")
print (student_mat.head(2))
print (student_pos.head(2))
```

Output:
[image]